# cmake on Solaris 10 Sparc: Configured not to use shared libraries?

Tags: cmake, solaris, sparc

I'm trying to port some software over to Solaris 10 Sparc, using GCC 3.4.6, and the software's build system uses `cmake`. When I run the command `cmake CMakeLists.txt`, I get a lot of output like this:

```
ADD_LIBRARY for library <library_name> is used with the SHARED 
option, but the target platform supports only STATIC libraries.
Building it STATIC instead. This may lead to problems.
```

Obviously Solaris 10 Sparc supports shared libraries, and I have built this software on x86 Solaris 10 before.

Anyone run into this or can provide direction? I'm about to dive into the cmake source to figure out if it has issues with Sparc Solaris.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After fighting with this a couple hours, and making little headway, I decided to install cmake-2.8.6 from [OpenCSW](http://www.opencsw.org/) using [`pkgutil`](http://pkgutil.net), and this issue cleared up.

Also asked this question in `#cmake@irc.freenode.net` before I fixed it, looks to be an issue with cmake 2.6.4 on Sparc Solaris 10.